# Can an Arduino Uno be used to measure the frequency of a square wave of up to 600 kHz?

Tags: pulsein

I am doing a project with a color sensor, where the output of the color sensor is a PWM square wave.

To measure its frequency using an Arduino Uno I am using the `pulseIn()` function, but I can't get the correct result.

Can an Arduino Uno measure a frequency of up to 600 kHz using the `pulseIn()` function?

Comment: `I can't get the correct result` ... what does that mean? ... what result do you get?

Comment: Do you want to measure the frequency or duty cycle?

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for pulseIn](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/pulsein/) states that it can be used for intervals of 10 microseconds to 3 minutes.

600 kHz *frequency* will have an *interval* of 1.6 microseconds and thus is not suitable for this application. (1 / 600000 = 0.000001666).

I have code on [my web page about timers](https://www.gammon.com.au/timers) for a sketch that can measure up to 8 MHz with only 0.5% error.

This code is reproduced below:

```cpp
// Timer and Counter example
// Author: Nick Gammon
// Date: 17th January 2012

// Input: Pin D5

// these are checked for in the main program
volatile unsigned long timerCounts;
volatile boolean counterReady;

// internal to counting routine
unsigned long overflowCount;
unsigned int timerTicks;
unsigned int timerPeriod;

void startCounting (unsigned int ms) 
  {
  counterReady = false;         // time not up yet
  timerPeriod = ms;             // how many 1 ms counts to do
  timerTicks = 0;               // reset interrupt counter
  overflowCount = 0;            // no overflows yet

  // reset Timer 1 and Timer 2
  TCCR1A = 0;             
  TCCR1B = 0;              
  TCCR2A = 0;
  TCCR2B = 0;

  // Timer 1 - counts events on pin D5
  TIMSK1 = bit (TOIE1);   // interrupt on Timer 1 overflow

  // Timer 2 - gives us our 1 ms counting interval
  // 16 MHz clock (62.5 ns per tick) - prescaled by 128
  //  counter increments every 8 µs. 
  // So we count 125 of them, giving exactly 1000 µs (1 ms)
  TCCR2A = bit (WGM21) ;   // CTC mode
  OCR2A  = 124;            // count up to 125  (zero relative!!!!)

  // Timer 2 - interrupt on match (ie. every 1 ms)
  TIMSK2 = bit (OCIE2A);   // enable Timer2 Interrupt

  TCNT1 = 0;      // Both counters to zero
  TCNT2 = 0;     

  // Reset prescalers
  GTCCR = bit (PSRASY);        // reset prescaler now
  // start Timer 2
  TCCR2B =  bit (CS20) | bit (CS22) ;  // prescaler of 128
  // start Timer 1
  // External clock source on T1 pin (D5). Clock on rising edge.
  TCCR1B =  bit (CS10) | bit (CS11) | bit (CS12);
  }  // end of startCounting

ISR (TIMER1_OVF_vect)
  {
  ++overflowCount;               // count number of Counter1 overflows  
  }  // end of TIMER1_OVF_vect


//******************************************************************
//  Timer2 Interrupt Service is invoked by hardware Timer 2 every 1 ms = 1000 Hz
//  16Mhz / 128 / 125 = 1000 Hz

ISR (TIMER2_COMPA_vect) 
  {
  // grab counter value before it changes any more
  unsigned int timer1CounterValue;
  timer1CounterValue = TCNT1;  // see datasheet, page 117 (accessing 16-bit registers)
  unsigned long overflowCopy = overflowCount;

  // see if we have reached timing period
  if (++timerTicks < timerPeriod) 
    return;  // not yet

  // if just missed an overflow
  if ((TIFR1 & bit (TOV1)) && timer1CounterValue < 256)
    overflowCopy++;

  // end of gate time, measurement ready

  TCCR1A = 0;    // stop timer 1
  TCCR1B = 0;    

  TCCR2A = 0;    // stop timer 2
  TCCR2B = 0;    

  TIMSK1 = 0;    // disable Timer1 Interrupt
  TIMSK2 = 0;    // disable Timer2 Interrupt
    
  // calculate total count
  timerCounts = (overflowCopy << 16) + timer1CounterValue;  // each overflow is 65536 more
  counterReady = true;              // set global flag for end count period
  }  // end of TIMER2_COMPA_vect

void setup () 
  {
  Serial.begin(115200);       
  Serial.println("Frequency Counter");
  } // end of setup

void loop () 
  {
  // stop Timer 0 interrupts from throwing the count out
  byte oldTCCR0A = TCCR0A;
  byte oldTCCR0B = TCCR0B;
  TCCR0A = 0;    // stop timer 0
  TCCR0B = 0;    
  
  startCounting (500);  // how many ms to count for

  while (!counterReady) 
     { }  // loop until count over

  // adjust counts by counting interval to give frequency in Hz
  float frq = (timerCounts *  1000.0) / timerPeriod;

  Serial.print ("Frequency: ");
  Serial.print ((unsigned long) frq);
  Serial.println (" Hz.");
  
  // restart timer 0
  TCCR0A = oldTCCR0A;
  TCCR0B = oldTCCR0B;
  
  // let serial stuff finish
  delay(200);
  }   // end of loop
```

---

> Whether Arduino UNO can measure the frequency upto 600 KHz if we use the pulseIn() function?

No. Not using pulseIn. However see the code above for a way of measuring such a frequency.